# Where can I find information about prior Israel/Gaza conflicts?

Tags: israel, war

The recent fighting between Israel and Gaza has me wondering about prior conflicts that came before this one. Is there a bipartisan source detailing prior significant conflicts between the two entities? By *significant* I'm thinking about events that in terms of timeframe, casualties, or effect.

Comment: I think that the FAQ disallows asking for reference images. However, I'm no moderator.

Comment: I doubt you will find a bipartisan source, but for a collection of actions you'd probably be better off performing some Google searches as there probably isn't a collection about them that won't be biased one way or the other

Comment: an advice ,go to Fox news and aljazera ,both are opposite

Comment: I came across an attempt at a non-partisan timeline for the latest conflict a few days ago. If I can find it again I'll put up a link.

Comment: Closed for the following reason: "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". More specifically the polling portion. Any questions that asks for opinions or a list of any nature does not fit within our guidelines. If you can reword the question I will be happy to consider reopening.

Comment: Also, "Gaza" [never existed as a separate political entity prior to 2000s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Gaza), therefore strictly speaking the only "Israel/Gaza" conflict you can talk about was operation Cast Lead.

Comment: This also falls into the "Asking for reference material" category of the [FAQ]. If you have a specific question, however, feel free to ask.

Comment: Finally found the timeline, starting from Nov 8: http://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2012/11/who-started-the-israel-gaza-conflict/265374/ . For history before then, look up the wikipedia entries on Gaza and Palestine.